# Which trigonometric function is most appropriate?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to figure out which trigonometric function is most appropriate for image below.

What I have tried:

```
function(x,theta){
theta*acos(theta+1)*x
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this takes it to the 'power of' like in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an oridinary cosine being raised to a power. It is written that way by convention to save parentheses and to make it clear that it is the result of applying the cosine which is raised to the power (rather than raising the argument to a power prior to taking its cosine). Use:

```
f <- function(x,theta){
    theta*cos(x)^(theta + 1)
}
```